# thread.sleep is messing with stopwatch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stopwatch

I'm using a stopwatch to know how long some operations run for points (game) system.

I'm defining it like this:

```
Stopwatch sekunde = new Stopwatch();
long tocke;
long glavnetocke;
long cas;
```

tocke and glavnetocke are points.

Then in "construct" I need to do this:

```
 sekunde.Start();
 Thread.Sleep(10000);
 sekunde.Stop();
```

If I don't do Thread sleep for 10000 it won't work.

Later in event handlers I use it like this:

```
        sekunde.Start();
        viewer.Clear();
        viewer.DrawBody(body, 10.0, Brushes.Green, 10.0, Brushes.Green);
        sekunde.Stop();
        cas = (long)sekunde.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        tocke = tocke + ((cas / 10));
        if (tocke > 200)
        {
             glavnetocke = glavnetocke + 1;
             tocke = 0;
        }
```

viewer is to draw body of the person standing in front of a camera. 
If I leave thread.sleep to 10000 it will work, otherwise it will not. But I need this to go away, because it stops the whole program. Even thou it happens only after I press a button in my form, I need to wait 10sec, before starting. Was thinking of just adding loading screen, but it doesn't work, as it freezes the whole program, so it doesn't show the loading gif.

EDIT:

well, as you can see that "tocke = tocke +((cas / 10));
tocke is always 0 if I remove thread.sleep or even lower the sleep number. Does stopwatch need time to initialize or something?
I want to get time of how long the operation runs to a long type variable so I can then use it for ingame points calculating. (cas = (long)sekunde.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;)

Comment: Please consider editing your question. What do you mean by it doesn't work? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @kuskmen I edited...

Comment: It must work without any Thread.Sleep. May be you look at sekunde.Elapsed.TotalSeconds when it's less than 1 second? Look for ticks or milliseconds elepsed

Comment: I assume, the "sekunde.Stop();" after the sleep is just for testing the sleep?  Otherwise your stopwatch is not going to be started...

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev then why does it work, if I leave Thread.Sleep, otherwise not? I'm not looking at it when it's less than 1 second.

Comment: @Trey no, I somebody answered similar question, and added thread.sleep in construct and it worked, so I did the same and it worked. If I remove sekunde.start, thread.sleep and sekunde.stop it won't work anymore.

Comment: You are casting `TotalSeconds` as a `long` when in it is a `double`, so you are chopping off the fraction part, so `0.5` seconds will become `0`.

Comment: @DaveBecker omg, how could I not see that? It works now, thanks. Can you post it as an answer so I can verify it? Also, I still don't know why it works when I leave thread.sleep(10000) (anyother number it won't work), weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By casting `TotalSeconds` as a `long` you are chopping off the fraction part. I've redone your example using `double`s and it seems to work for me:

```
Stopwatch sekunde = new Stopwatch();
long glavnetocke = 0;
double cas;
double tocke = 0;

sekunde.Start();
sekunde.Stop();

cas = sekunde.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
tocke = tocke + ((cas / 10));
if (tocke > 200)
{
    glavnetocke = glavnetocke + 1;
    tocke = 0;
}
```

Result

`cas = 0.0000015` (on my setup)